# How to Install an APK that only supports Armeabi-v7a on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, arm64

Device: M2 Macbook

The APK doesn't work on any Android Version that supports Arm64-v8a on my end.
The images that support Armeabi-v7a under "Other Images" take forever for the device to boot.

Wanted to use it in Android Studio Device Manager, but it didn't install -
"App Not Installed".

Is there any settings I can change in Android Studio to be able to install it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.